# Error on converting date time to specific format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am newbie to SQL Server and facing an issue. I am trying to convert date time which is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Used below code to change the format, which works well if `dd <=12` and throws error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value` if `dd>12`

```
Declare @LastTime datetime   
set @LastTime = '2015-06-12 12:08:18.690'      

 select convert(varchar, @LastTime, 101)
```

Tried with other output formats ([from here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)) as well but no luck. Is there a way to fix the issue. I am using SQL Server 2008 version. Referred to many posts here but none of them solved the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from `set @LastTime = ...` not from your `select convert(...)`

The error is because your current `dateformat` is `dmy` (implicitly set by default language)

If you would rather just change your `dateformat` then `set dateformat mdy;` will allow you to set `@LastTime` with the string `2016-06-13` (June 13th 2016).

If you don't want to mess with changing your `dateformat` you can specify the style of the string you use with `convert` when you are setting `@LastTime`, in this case that would be `121` (`120` works as well).

rextester: http://rextester.com/CWZP33091

try this:

```
declare @LastTime datetime;
set @LastTime = convert(datetime,'2015-06-12 12:08:18.690',121);

select convert(varchar, @LastTime, 101);
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the Date format try using this:
    SET DATE FORMAT DMY
just write it on the screen, select it and execute it,that will allow you to work with DATE types in the format that you want till you close the session. the DATE type will be a String

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the MSDN documentation for cast and convert at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

I'd guess that style 103 is the right one for you.

Give it a try with

select convert(varchar, @LastTime, 103)

I don't have the opportunity to check it out right now, as I don't have a MS SQL Server at hand.

As style 101 converts 'mm/dd/yyyy' it's clear why dd>12 causes an error, as convert is trying to convert 'mm' as a month with valid values from 1 - 12 and you provide 'dd' from 1-31.

Hope that helps

Take care

Andreas